# Is $d(x,y)=|x-y|^3$ a metric? Justify.

Tags: metric-spaces

I have been able to show that

1. $d(x,y) \geq 0 $
2. If $d(x,y) = 0$ , then $x=y$
3. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
4. For the fourth property,

Let $z \in X$, then
$d(x,y) = |x-y|^3 =|x-z+z-y|^3$

(by triangle inequality)

$\leq (|x-z| + |z-y|)^3$
$= |x-z|^3 + |z-y|^3 + 3|x-z||z-y|(|x-z|+|z-y|)$

After this, since the given expression can't always be  $\leq|x-z|^3 + |z-y|^3$, d is not a metric. To justify I have to take one example but which??

Comment: A metric on what?  The real numbers?  In any case, a single counterexample is all you need to disprove a result.

Comment: Have you tried even one example? Seems to me that any $x,y,z$ with $x<z<y$ should suffice...

Comment: See for example  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3820282/42969

Comment: See [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4511940/977780).

Comment: @CarlosAdir In one dimension that $p$-norm works out to $||v||_p=|v_1|\ne|v_1|^p$.

Comment: You just need one example to prove it is not a metric. Is $d(0,2)\leq d(0,1)+d(1,2)?$

Comment: $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ induced a metric on $\Bbb{R}$ via isometry iff $f$ is injective.See [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4511940/977780).

Comment: Note, your argument only shows that you can't prove the triangle inequality this way.  "since the given expression can't always be ..., $d$ is not a metric." That is wrong, because you haven't shown that the given expression can't always be...."

Comment: Your proof can be made correct by assuming that $z$ is between $x$ and $y.$ Then $|x-y|=|x-z|+|z-y|,$ and you get $d(x,y)=d(x,z)+d(z,y)+k(x,y,z)$ for some non-negative $k(x,y,z),$ where $k$ is not zero if $x,y,z$ are distinct. That lets you find an example easily.

Answer (score 5):

$d(1, 2)  = 1, d(2, 3) = 1$  but $d(1, 3) = 8$. Therefore, $d(1, 3) > d(1, 2) + d(2, 3)$